# fullcalendar json is not working

Tags: fullcalendar

I am having a hardtime trying to populate events on fullcalendar, following is my code, trying to fetch data from mysql

class mycalendarleaves extends Generic{
 function calendar_LeaveDetails(){

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$params = array( ':user_id' => $this->user_id );
$stmt   = parent::query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE TYPE = 'leave' AND leave_status='approved' AND sender_id = :user_id;", $params);

while($value = $stmt->fetch()) :    
    $_SESSION['cal_data']  = array(
            'id'    => $value['id'],
            'title' =>  $value['sender_name'],
            'start' =>  "$year-$month-10"
            );
    endwhile;
}
```

}

echo json_encode($_SESSION['cal_data']);

$mycalendarleaves = new mycalendarleaves();

here is the script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: "calendar.php",
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                '(should probably update your database)');
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }
    }); 
});
```

I dont get any error, the calendar still appears blank without data. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, incase someone else is having a problem may be this will help them as well.

following is my function that is fetching data from mysql

```
 function calendar_EventDetails(){


$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$this->id = $_SESSION['id'];
$params = array( ':id' => $this->id );
$stmt   = parent::query("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE TYPE = 'event' AND status='approved' AND id = :id;", $params);

unset($_SESSION['events']);
while($value = $stmt->fetch()) :

    $_SESSION['events'][]  = array(
            'id'    => $value['id'],
            'title' =>  $value['name'],
            'start' =>  "$year-$month-10"

            );
    endwhile;
}
```

Following is the script which is calling the php file where the above function is placed

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: "calendar.php",
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                '(should probably update your database)');
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }
    }); 
});
```